# How to click a "drop down window" using applescript

Tags: menu, click, applescript

So my problem is in disk warrior there is a drop down window under the "Directory" pane that i can't get applescript to "click". Is there anyway to tell applescript to "click" the drop down window and then click a disk from the list? My boSS wants this whole code automated and this is the one part I'm not sure if i can automate. Here is my code:

```
do shell script "open /Applications/DiskWarrior.app"
delay 3
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "my password"
    delay 2
    keystroke return
    delay 3
    keystroke tab
    delay 3
    keystroke return
    delay 20
    --Delay 20 to allow time for the application to fully load
    end tell
```

After diskwarrior is open the next step would to be select the disk i want to rebuild but as i said i am unsure how to tell applescript to "click" it.

Anyone have some suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
do shell script "open -a DiskWarrior"
delay 5
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SecurityAgent"
        set value of text field 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "password"
        click button 2 of group 2 of window 1
    end tell
    delay 5
    tell process "DiskWarrior"
        set frontmost to true
        tell pop up button 1 of window 1
            click
            click menu item 2 of menu 1
        end tell
        set visible to false -- workaround for a glitch in the DiskWarrior UI
        set visible to true
        click button "Rebuild" of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

I couldn't get clicking the rebuild button to work. Recording actions in Automator worked though:

[image]

Comment: Can you get the position of the "Rebuild" button? If so then you can use my MouseTools tool to click at the position. Get it here: http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html

Comment: Ill try the position idea, if that doesn't work i honestly don't think anything else will. If any one else has ideas thou please done hesitate to share them.